# How to Web Scrape Youtube Comments using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I apologize if this question seems a bit basic, but my html skills are still a work in progress. I am attempting to grab all comments from a Youtube video using BeautifulSoup, but I am having trouble finding the specific tags that would identify the comments. I have scanned the page source over a few times and cannot for the life of me get any comments to print. Any help would be appreciated.

I have noticed that the comments seem to be stored in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYnG4.png) block of html.

My code is as the following:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQgXKtPSzUI'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
#html parsing
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

#Attempts to grab comments
comments= page_soup.find_all('div',{'class':'contents'})

print(len(comments))
print(comments)
```

Comment: YT may use JavaScript which is not executed by `BS`. You will need `Selenium` which let you control web browser when it runs JavaScript on YT. BTW: I use `DevTool` built-in in Chrome/Firefox to see HTML code after JavaScript adds elements.

Comment: I found it read comments from `https://www.youtube.com/comment_service_ajax?action_get_comments=1&pbj=1&ctoken=EhYSC1hRZ1hLdFBTelVJwAEAyAEA4AEDGAY%3D&itct=CHYQuy8YAiITCNm7ysm63dcCFQXBHAod2uwC3Sj4HQ==` but it gives error 403 if you try to download without coockies which you would get from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQgXKtPSzUI so it more complex than on other web pages. Using Selenium it should be easier.